# Custom binary tree object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I'm trying to write a custom binary tree class. I already have the node:

```
class Node:

def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
    self.value = value
    self.kwargs = kwargs

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)

def __str__(self):
    main_str = '{value: ' + str(self.value)
    for key, value in self.kwargs.items():
        main_str += ', ' + str(key) + ': ' + str(value)
    main_str += '}'

    return main_str
```

The node uses kwargs because i'm using it also for other things. The problem i'm having is in the tree class:

```
from models.node import Node
class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add_element(self, value):
        node = Node(value, left=None, right=None)

        if not self.root:
            self.root = node

        else:
            self.__add_element_recursive(self.root, value)

    def __add_element_recursive(self, parent, value):

        if not parent:
            node = Node(value, left=None, right=None)
            parent = node

        elif value > parent.value:
            self.__add_element_recursive(parent.right, value)

        else:
            self.__add_element_recursive(parent.left, value)
```

This clearly doesn't work because the parameters in python don't get passed as references but as new instances. For example, I know this would work in C++ because I can just pass pointers to the methods.

How do I create the method to add a value to the tree? I think I might be missing something really obvious here.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `This clearly doesn't work because the parameters in python don't get passed as references but as new instances.` If you pass a `Node` instance as a parameter, the function will receive a reference to that Node not a copy or new instance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the created node to a branch of the tree.

try this:

```
def __add_element_recursive(self, parent, value):
    if value > parent.value:
        if parent.right: # there's a right node: lets go there
            self.__add_element_recursive(parent.right, value)
        else: # No node: we have found our spot
            parent.right = Node(value, left=None, right=None)
    elif parent.left: # There's a left node...lets go there
        self.__add_element_recursive(parent.left, value)
    else: # No node: we have found our spot
        parent.left = Node(value, left=None, right=None)
```